# Create a daily repeat service that starts to record and stops to record sensor data at given time in Android

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, repeatingalarm

I am new to Android. And I want to daily record sensor data at a user given time and stop to record at another user given time.

I think I could use AlarmManager. Right now I have a SensorService class that records sensor data. I have two timePicker to record user's input time.

Below is the codes that I get from [Android training](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)

```
        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        // Set the alarm to start at given time.
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, start_hour);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, start_min);


        // With setInexactRepeating(), you have to use one of the AlarmManager interval
        // constants--in this case, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY.
        alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

I still don't know how to integrate my SensorService class with the AlarmManager. (I have methods called startLogging and stopLogger in the sensroService class).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I eventually used TimerTask and Timer. They are much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple short android application that uses the alarm manager located [here](https://github.com/timobarrett/WeatherTracker)
When the alarm triggers, the application makes a REST call, collects data and stores it in a local sqlite3 database.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My main concern is that how could I stop the data collection. In my case I am going to collect data for a time interval and stop collecting at the setting time.

Comment: the alarmmanager provides the ability to schedule a task periodically.  So the start of your data collection process is fairly straight forward.  Your application would need to know when to stop collecting data. That's something you would have to implement.

Comment: Got it. Another question is that if the AlarmManager has to be in a separate class that extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver. Is it possible that I include it in the MainActivity class?

Comment: Not to self promote but have a look at https://github.com/timobarrett/WeatherTracker - found that the class layout worked the best of a number of approaches I tried.